# How do I make sure all of the code in an on click function gets executed before opening a new window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tracking

I have a function that triggers on click that sends off one tracking event to Google, and one request to my server to create a record in the database.

Everything works fine for desktop users but for some mobile users Google will record click events that my database doesn't. After some research I think I've narrowed down the problem to the fact that opening a new window via a web view causes the previous window to stop executing JavaScript, so the request to my server never gets sent. I temporarily mitigated the problem by adding a small delay to the window opening but recently I've noticed that the built-in pop-up blockers in web browsers are blocking the window so I've had to remove the delay.

Html:

```
<a ng-click="captureClick(pageUrl)" target="_blank">
```

JS:

```
$scope.captureClick = function(link){
  //Send Google Analytics click event
  ga('send', 'event', 'click');

  var linkObj = {
    //Create object with click details
  };
  Links.save(linkObj);

  $window.open(link);
};
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Tapping something on a mobile screen is not exactly the same as clicking something on a PC. Depending on how you have it coded you may not be handling the touch events correctly to execute your click logic.

Comment: I've added a simplified version of my code

Answer (score 0):

Use Promises:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // your code to your server
  // after your server replied to the call
  resolve();
}).then(function(data) {
  // google track code
});
```

Comment: Would this behave differently than using a callback? I put the $window.open call in a callback and the popup blocker stopped it.

Comment: Links.save(linkObj);

It should return a promise, in order to concatenate here the call to google tracking and the window.open

Did you get me?

Comment: Using a promise did not work. Initiating a window open from any kind of callback is blocked on mobile.